# Under scrutiny in this sentence, is it correct?

Tags: meaning

Original text:

Some people think governments should take measures regarding the healthy lifestyle of individuals. Other think it must be managed by individuals.

Paraphrasing:

Although it's sometimes thought that the healthy lifestyle of each person ought to under scrutiny by governments, other people believe that it's compulsory to manage on their own.

---

Question:

Should I use under scrutiny to replace measures? I looked up to synonyms but I could not find a better one to describe it better.

Also, is it scrutiny a negative word to use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm wondering if 'take measures' is being interpreted along the lines of 'take measurements'. Then the paraphrase would be good, bit it would probably be a misinterpretation.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your concern. It was an open question and I had to develop the main idea and paraphrase a new sentence out of it. 

Read through your comment then went on to a dictionary and now I have a question. Hope you can clarify it for me.

Does 'take measure' = ' take action' then?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I think it's more like that. Essentially the 'take measures regarding' means 'implement a policy in relation to'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrutiny isn’t a negative word; however, a lot depends on the connotation of a word in a sentence.

An alternative could be either of the following:

- Some people opine that it should be the governments to take measures
  concerning the healthy lifestyle of its people. Others think it is an
  affair people should manage on their own.
- Some people consider that maintaining healthy lifestyle of its people is the obligation of the governments. Others think it is an individual matter that people should manage on their own.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This started as a comment, but it got too long ...

Scrutiny is not always negative, as sometimes scrutiny is required, as in when someone does *due diligence*.

Nevertheless, I don't think the paraphrase is right.

In your example **scrutiny** seems to imply **prying** (which *is* negative), but **take measures** doesn't have this implication.

For example, a possible measure would be free (and possibly compulsory) health checks. This isn't **prying** by the government because the information from the health check isn't available to the government.

On the other hand, if you had to fill in a lifestyle survey and send it to a government office, then that would (or could) be **prying**.

So I guess your paraphrase might still be *true* (it depends on the proposed measures), but it adds to the original sentence and therefore isn't a fair paraphrase.